# WhirlyGlobe initial rotation is offset

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When I initialise and show a [Whirlyglobe](http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/) in my Swift App, the rotation is offset by 90 degrees, always showing the globe on it's side.

[image: Whirly screenshot]

I would like to start off with a north-south orientation.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `– animateToPosition:time:` once you have your globe or map setup. I suggest having a delay before executing this method after setting up your globe.
For example in Objective-C:

```
// Your code to setup WhirlyGlobeViewController...

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.000001 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MaplyCoordinate coords = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(0, 0);
        [self.globe animateToPosition:coords height:2.0 heading:0 time:1];
      });
```